# Join raspbian in a samba domain

Tags: raspbian, pi-3b+, samba, dns

I'm trying for an `rpi` in a `samba` domain. I researched a lot but nothing works ...

I would ask for a tutorial from you guys or even the link to some that worked. I'll use the same `raspbian`.

I'm really in doubt about what might be failing, I will not even put smb.conf or anything like that, because I've tried different things ... I want to go from scratch myself, to understand and see how it's done.

Thank you immensely who can help! (~°-°)~

Comment: This is not a question specific to Raspberry Pi. You should ask at https://superuser.com. I think you will get quicker better answers.

Comment: Hmm ok. I'll go there. Ty xD